# Java output not working as I would like it to

Tags: java

```
public class FooCorporation {
    public int hoursWorked;
    public double basePay;
    double salary;

    public FooCorporation (int a, double b) {
        a= hoursWorked;
        b = basePay;
    }

    void mySalary(){
        if (hoursWorked>40){
            salary = 40*basePay + ((hoursWorked - 40)*basePay*1.5);
            System.out.println(salary);
        } else {
            salary = hoursWorked*basePay ;
            System.out.println(salary);
        }
    }
}

public class SalaryTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FooCorporation employee1 = new FooCorporation(4, 7.5);
        FooCorporation employee2 = new FooCorporation(47, 8.2);
        FooCorporation employee3 = new FooCorporation(59, 10);

        employee1.mySalary();
        employee2.mySalary();
        employee3.mySalary();
    }
}
```

The output of this code is always 0.0 and cant understand why. I was thinking that maybe the constructor is not working or there is some sort of problem withe the salary double. It would be cool if someone could look at it .. thanks

Comment: Assignment sets the left side to the right side's value, e.g., `beingSet = fromThisValue` modifies `beingSet`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your constructor assignment is back to front

```
public FooCorporation (int a, double b) {
         a= hoursWorked;
         b = basePay;
        }
```

should be

```
public FooCorporation (int a, double b) {
         hoursWorked = a;
         basePay = b;
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

You have a mistake here:

```
  public FooCorporation (int a, double b) {
     a= hoursWorked;
     b = basePay;
     }
```

Try to assign a value to a variable in a constructor like this:

```
  public FooCorporation (int a, double b) {
     this.hoursWorked = a;
     this.basePay = b;
    }
```